# pycharm editor tabs not showing up

Tags: pycharm

I can't seem to get editor tabs to show up. I'm running the community version. It is a professional feature? I've tried to "pin active tab" and "Editor Tabs" in "General"... "Placement" shows "Top", but I don't see it.

Comment: Are you sure about this ? Try reinstalling pycharm. All settings you tried worked perfectly for me, editor tabs should be hidden if "Placement" is selected as _None_ .

Comment: i upgraded to 2018.3.1 and it worked. i was using 2018.1

Comment: I can't help. I'm also using that version, and everything can be setup in settings normally.

Comment: You already did. Thanks.